# Div height is Different in IE Compare with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, html, xhtml

When I add the height to div tag It is not same height ie and firefox. I cannot put 100% on the div tag. Can you please any Help me to fix this issue. I have attached Css Code here, Please [Click here](http://www.excelproperty.lk/property/newspaper-advertising/) to see the  site.

```
#payment{
    width: 265px;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(50,50,50,0.46);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(50,50,50,0.46);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(50,50,50,0.46);
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    height: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 549px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a machine to check any cross-browser issues, so I cannot help you with your height problem. But I would like to mention that there is no need to use the float:right property while using the position and left properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with padding. IE and firefox parse padding differently. Firefox adds padding with height/width of the div (so the total height/width will be defined height/width+padding) wherein IE doesn't add that. This occurs with older versions (< IE9).

You can try following for older versions of IE.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
#payment{
    width: 285px; /* original width + padding on left and right */
    height: 250px;/* original height + padding on top and bottom */
    padding: 10px;
}
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're using a Quirk mode doctype on the page.

Switch the

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE>
```

or something more proper than a quirk mode.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE> to <!DOCTYPE HTML>